# Populating a temp table with two different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I was wondering how i can extend my current stored procedure to populate a temporary table.

My current temporary table inserts a row when it finds a record from a table with the status of 'Processed'. I want to now populate all records that are 'Processed' but also all records of that similar 'ID' that are 'Processing'. So if Processed does not exist, take 'Processing if its there'

I currently just build my temp table and i guess i need a conditional case here,

```
INSERT INTO @TBL1
SELECT status_fkey, NULL, status_date_modified
FROM tbl_records
WHERE status_token = 'Processed'
```

In this table i also have status name which is the same across all status etc.. not sure if that will help my conditional case?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Nobody can really help here because we have no idea what your table is like, what your data is like or what you are trying to do. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your description is unclear. "populating all records that are 'Processed' but also all records of that similar 'ID' that are 'Processing'" sounds the opposite to "So if Processed does not exist, take 'Processing if its there'"

Comment: What does "of that similar 'ID' " mean?   There is no `ID` column in your query.